# Why isn't Ionic command recognised in Windows cmd?

Tags: ionic-framework

I install the Ionic framework and after that Windows shows:

```
ionic is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

But if I go to user/AppData/Roaming/npm I have the batch of Ionic.
How can I add it to command line? Without opening this folder.
Thanks.

Comment: You must have forgotten the `-g` option when installing it: `npm install -g ionic`.

Comment: no i don't... i have install correctly

Comment: Check that you have the environment variable created in the path. Something like `C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: thanks you're the guy :D